# How to get seo friendly url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on a CMS currently and my urls currently look something like this *example.com/index.php?p=1* how can I make it so that each post which is as *p* has a page url like WordPress does where it would be the title.

```
$ArticleName = "Some Example Post";
```

The output URL should look like this *example.com/some-example-post.php*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this perhaps.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ /index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the portion at the end means `p=$1` does this cover ALL potential numbers or just number 1?

Comment: It is a placeholder foe the first parameter the more parameters you include so the number will change. The characters to the left after the carat `^` are the substitution foe the first placeholder - in this case `p` ~ `$1` - it does NOT actually mean the number `1`

Comment: when I say `foe` I do, of course, mean `for` - too early to see straight and not enough coffee ;-)